# share database between desktop and android app

Tags: android, .net, database

I´m creating a simple database, let´s say something like NBA players with statistics and pictures. I want to be able to edit the database in my desktop C# application and then consult it on my phone .. When there is no internet!

it is Ok to transfer files from desktop to phone manually. It is Ok to download in the app and then get to the place where there is no internet.

The question is .. what´s my best option here? one big xml? or json? a one-file database like sqllite?

I have expertise on C# but I´m new to android and the whole internet connectivity thing. So I´m specially interested on something that´s easily accesible from android phone.

What would you do ?

Comment: can someone comment why the downvotes? It really feels like a design decision with multiple solutions..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better that you use a single database for the 2 application using mySQL, a local network is necessary, but an internet will be optional. Android will Send & Retrieve Data in the database. Here are some links you can use( [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html), [sample codes](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) ).

Comment: I'm using parse.com, their android SDK supports offline storage

Comment: I love the idea of Just one db. Just to clarify,  where would it be,  in the Internet? In the desktop and then the Android will make local copies (for online usage)???

Comment: It depends on you. You can do it in a webhost, if you are going for an internet/online usage you should have purchase/use a free webhost, but if you are going for a local(adhoc), you can use Xampp,Wampp etc.